# How to restrict user from selecting dates after 2months/60days from the date picker

Tags: javascript, date

Hi I am trying to restrict date entry from present day to the next 60 days. For restricting the previous dates I used `minDate: 0` and it worked fine. But when I used `maxDate: 60` the dates in stopped appearing.

The code which I used:

```
$('#dob').datetimepicker({
   format:'Y-m-d',
   formatDate:'Y-m-d',     
   minDate: 0,
   maxDate: 60
});
```

This is what it shows while entering date:

[image]

Can you please help how to rectify it?

Comment: Try changing the maxDate option to '+2m'. If it doesn't work, provide us with a fiddle where you reproduced the problem.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AcbUf/) Check this link to setup `maxdate` for your datepicker as @Milanzor told

Comment: It doesn't work. Instead when I did it the datepicker didn't even appear. Sorry I am new to coding can you please tell me how and what to share in the fiddle you asked for. @Milanzor

Comment: You can go to https://jsfiddle.net/ and reproduce your problem in a separate environment. If you take the code that creates your datepicker and paste in it the Javascript box of jsfiddle, paste your HTML/CSS in their respective boxes and include the required scripts as external sources, like jQuery and jQuery UI (left sidebar). Save it and post the link, that way we can see what's going on.

Comment: If you're using libraries or plugins, add tags for them to attract people with those skills.

Answer (score 0):

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

```js
$('#dob').datetimepicker({
    format:'Y-m-d',
    formatDate:'Y-m-d',     
    minDate: 0,
   // minDate:'-1970/01/02',//yesterday is minimum date(for today use 0 or -1970/01/01)
   // maxDate:'+1970/01/02'//tomorrow is maximum date calendar
    maxDate: '+1970/03/03' // two months later, the feb is a bit special.
});
```